# Woocommerce Sorting with "Select" type attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using "woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby"

I'm trying to orderby attributes. I'm sucessfull with Text Type since it registers the inputed meta_value in _postmeta ( SQL )

However, "SELECT" type attributes, lists the "term_id" located in _terms

So for example:

Laptop - with Size: 17   -- if is "TEXT" type, the meta_value for the product will be 17

If is "SELECT" type, the meta_value will be 4698  <-- This 4698 is the term_id  -> the term_id in _terms will have 17 as name

This is the link of the complete function i'm using: [Github link](https://gist.github.com/ChromeOrange/3135986)

```
case $entry_case:
  $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
  $sort_args['order']    = 'ASC';
  $sort_args['meta_key'] = 'pa_laptop-size';
```

I know i can change to Text, and easily fix the problem. However, there are over 1000 entries for this attribute. So i need to change the function no matter what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug resolved by WooCommerce Plugin - Ver 3.1.1 solved it

Thanks.